# 2.6 Drop a perpendicular

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Euclidea 2.6 Drop a perpendicular. The Thales theory allow one to construct a right angle at point "a" it seems. Not on the segment. My solution which got 2 stars is construct line from "a" to random point "b" on the segment. Bisect this line at "c" and draw circle from "c" to "a". You have now created a diameter which allows us to use Thales. Where the circle intersects the segment "d" is perpendicular to "a". I've seen a construction using a random point outside the segment to start which earned 3 stars but I can't remember it or refind it! Help please?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoXANQh-HLM

Comment: Aha, thank you. The line between the intersections of 2 circles whose centres are on a line must be at right-angles to the line. Sooooo obvious!

Comment: why is it perpendicular?